PowerBI - Fabric License Integration
I have a Power BI Pro license on my account.
We have a workspace assigned to a Fabric capacity wherein there are some lakehouses and fabric warehouses already created.
I have been added as an admin in the workspace but I am still not able to see any other experience other than Power BI and not able to create any lakehouse/data pieplines etc
Need some guidance.

In the tenant setting has the setting for allow fabric features been allowed, otherwise it will act as a Power BI capacity?

If you have Fabric Capacity set (have you double checked?), then you will get the Fabric experience. Have you cleared your browser cache and done a hard refresh on app.powerbi.com?


Below can also be the scenario wherein the admin portal settings might have been disabled for the user:

